# What model to use for forecasting when customers will arrive?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to build a model which will give the probability of every customer in a database will show up on a certain day (i.e. I pass in 8/25/19 and the list of all customers shows up with their respective probability). I have the logs for all customers transactions and the date. I'm thinking of using some sort of RNN to do this. Is this the proper way to do this? If not, what is the best way to do it? I want to discover the patterns and high confidence leads for which customers show up. There is around 400,000 records for 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

You have time series data. 
RNN is a good starting point. Check out [this step-by-step instructions](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-machine-learning-regression-framework-9ea33929009a) of sales prediction. RNN is an easy start and might give you really good quality. Also there is an adaptation of xgboost algorithm for time series that also gives a good quality, but might be slower.

Good luck!